# Misalignment with Many inline-block li Tags

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I'm having a weird, intermittent, unreproducible CSS layout issue. I have a bunch of li tags with divs inside them. ***Not always, but every once and awhile*** when I load the page in Chrome or Safari, the layout is misaligned:

Edit: The site is now live at: [www.socwall.com](http://www.socwall.com) if you want to try to reproduce. IE and Firefox don't seem to have the issue, just Safari and Chrome

[image]

If I wiggle the mouse around or move the scroll bar, it suddenly fixes itself:

[image]

I know inline-block is kind of sketchy to be using in the first place - do you think that is it?

Comment: without code looks like a puzzle to solve

Comment: Hey guys, just updated the question - the site is now live at: www.socwall.com. IE and Firefox don't seem to have the issue, just Safari and Chrome

Comment: I checked in Chrome now and it looks fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the page layout is being determined before the images finish loading. Does including height and width in the image tags fix the problem?

Comment: I just added a direct style tag to each image with the fixed dimensions of 290x260. I can't reproduce on my end, is it still happening to you?

Comment: No. I haven't been able to reproduce it after 20 refreshes. Before, it was happening every 2-3 loads.

Comment: Awesome, I have seen this before, you may want to consider adding the width and height as a rule in your style sheet and get rid of the ugly inline styles/extra markup

Comment: I usually include height and width as attributes, as arguably this is semantically meaningful to the image content, and it also avoids delaying the page layout and potential layout issues if an image asset is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested several times and no issues at all. It must have been some old CSS that was cached by your browser.

Try reseting your entire browser or deleting your cache and try testing again.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine on Safari and Chrome on my end (Mac).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment simply add this rule to your css style sheet:

```
.wallpaperList img {
     width:290px;
     height: 260px;
}
```

And remove all the inline style="..." from the images them selves

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution to avoid the inline-block, you could instead float:left.  If you are concerned about centering you can either:

1. Predefine a maximum amount of items per row and have each row as a containing div, and use the center floats trick here: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html
2. For your full width page, load in the content with jQuery based on the window width.  On window resize you would rerun the load content.  From here you can figure out how many items can go in each row based upon the outer widths of each item and the window size.

I know it seems like a lot as opposed to inline-block, but such is the path to perfection :)